# PHP could not execute query

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, post

i am using php **5.6.20**

in the admin page i am trying to Add product but it seems like the post dose not work and the query dose not executed 
[The database taple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4O5q.jpg) 
The Form

```
        <form id="myform"method="post"action="Admin.php">

        <table class="userinf">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2"><label class="labeli">Add Product</label></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="labelii">PID</label></td>
                <td><input id ="iitxt0" class ="itxt"type="text" name="PID" value="<?php echo $row["UID"]; ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="labelii">Name</label></td>
                <td><input id ="iitxt1" class ="itxt"type="text" name="Name" required value="<?php echo $row["Name"]; ?>" "></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="labelii">Picture</label></td>
                <td><input id ="iitxt2" class ="itxt" type="text" name="Picture" required value="<?php echo $row["Email"]; ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="labelii">Price</label></td>
                <td><input id ="iitxt3" class ="itxt" type = "text" name="Price" pattern="[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)" required value="<?php echo $row["PhoneNo"]; ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="labelii">Type</label></td>
                <td><input id ="iitxt4" class ="itxt" type="text" name="Type"  required value="<?php echo $row["CreditNo"]; ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="labelii">Stock</label></td>
                <td><input id ="iitxt5" class ="itxt"type="number" name="Stock" value="<?php echo $row["City"]; ?>"></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button type="submit" id="Sbutt" class="Ebutton" onclick="submitform()">Save</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

The PHP Code

```
<?php

        var_dump();
        if (isset($_POST["PID"]) && isset($_POST["Name"]) && isset($_POST["Picture"]) && isset($_POST["Price"]) && isset($_POST["Type"]) && isset($_POST["Stock"])){

        $PID=$_POST['PID'];
        $Name=$_POST['Name'];
        $Picture=$_POST['Picture'];
        $Price=floatval($_POST['Price']);
        $Type=$_POST['Type'];
        $Stock=intval($_POST['Stock']);
        $query="INSERT INTO `product` (`PID`, `Name`, `Picture`, `Price`, `Type`, `Stock`)"+
         +"VALUES ('$PID', '$Name', '$Picture','$Price', '$Type', '$Stock')";
        }
        if($_POST){
        if(!($database=mysql_connect("localhost","wadiahS","123456")))
          die("Could not connect to database</body></html>");
        if(!mysql_select_db("glow",$database))
          die("Could not open database</body></html>");
        if(!($result=mysql_query($query,$database))){
          print("<p>could not execute query</p>");
          die(mysql_error()."</body></html>");
        }
        mysql_close($database);
        }
   ?>
```

And when i try to post 
ii get the error
/// 
Warning: var_dump() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\pages\Admin.php on line 294
could not execute query

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1
///

Comment: You didn't add parameter for var dump. Add it in parentheses.

Comment: In the PHP code at Line 1 you are using  var_dump(); without any parameter.

Comment: the 1st line 'var_dump();' here is error.You need to put the variable which you want to view. Also check the line '$query="INSERT INTO `product` (`PID`, `Name`, `Picture`, `Price`, `Type`, `Stock`)"+
         +"VALUES ('$PID', '$Name', '$Picture','$Price', '$Type', '$Stock')";' '+' is not accepted by php. it should be '.'

Comment: is there any need to concatinate the query ?

Comment: thank you all it did solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concatenating the query using plus(+)
In PHP Strings are concatenating using dot(.)
Also either remove the var_dump() or add any parameter to it.

```
$query="INSERT INTO `product` (`PID`, `Name`, `Picture`, `Price`, `Type`, `Stock`)" . "VALUES ('$PID', '$Name', '$Picture','$Price', '$Type', '$Stock')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove empty var_dump() and `+` from query.

```
$query="INSERT INTO `product` (`PID`, `Name`, `Picture`, `Price`, `Type`, `Stock`) VALUES ('$PID', '$Name', '$Picture','$Price', '$Type', '$Stock')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you have syntax error in query. you need to replace you query code with below code i hope it's helpful. you have concatenate with (+) operator in PHP if you want concatenate  any thing you need use (.) operator. so please change your query variable with below given.

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO `product` (`PID`, `Name`, `Picture`, `Price`, `Type`, `Stock`) VALUES ('$PID', '$Name', '$Picture','$Price', '$Type', '$Stock')";
```

Replace your query variable with above.